# Click jQuery element targeted with css selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code and I want to click on the Reset Button.

```
 <div class="col-md-3 filter-buttons">
     <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit">Submit</button>
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://return.dev/ai?reset=1">Reset</a>
</div>
```

I tried with

```
$('.filter-buttons a.btn').click();
```

but doesn't work.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Your css selection will fetch an array. You have to get the element by iteration to assign the click function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to emulate the dom anchor element click, use,

```
$('.filter-buttons a.btn').get(0).click();
```

Otherwise it will trigger the jquery click event binded to that element. In this case you have not binded any click events to that anchor element.